# Downloading and unzipping a .zip file without writing to disk

Tags: python, unzip

I have managed to get my first python script to work which downloads a list of .ZIP files from a URL and then proceeds to extract the ZIP files and writes them to disk.

I am now at a loss to achieve the next step.

My primary goal is to download and extract the zip file and pass the contents (CSV data) via a TCP stream. I would prefer not to actually write any of the zip or extracted files to disk if I could get away with it.

Here is my current script which works but unfortunately has to write the files to disk.

```
import urllib, urllister
import zipfile
import urllib2
import os
import time
import pickle

# check for extraction directories existence
if not os.path.isdir('downloaded'):
    os.makedirs('downloaded')

if not os.path.isdir('extracted'):
    os.makedirs('extracted')

# open logfile for downloaded data and save to local variable
if os.path.isfile('downloaded.pickle'):
    downloadedLog = pickle.load(open('downloaded.pickle'))
else:
    downloadedLog = {'key':'value'}

# remove entries older than 5 days (to maintain speed)

# path of zip files
zipFileURL = "http://www.thewebserver.com/that/contains/a/directory/of/zip/files"

# retrieve list of URLs from the webservers
usock = urllib.urlopen(zipFileURL)
parser = urllister.URLLister()
parser.feed(usock.read())
usock.close()
parser.close()

# only parse urls
for url in parser.urls: 
    if "PUBLIC_P5MIN" in url:

        # download the file
        downloadURL = zipFileURL + url
        outputFilename = "downloaded/" + url

        # check if file already exists on disk
        if url in downloadedLog or os.path.isfile(outputFilename):
            print "Skipping " + downloadURL
            continue

        print "Downloading ",downloadURL
        response = urllib2.urlopen(downloadURL)
        zippedData = response.read()

        # save data to disk
        print "Saving to ",outputFilename
        output = open(outputFilename,'wb')
        output.write(zippedData)
        output.close()

        # extract the data
        zfobj = zipfile.ZipFile(outputFilename)
        for name in zfobj.namelist():
            uncompressed = zfobj.read(name)

            # save uncompressed data to disk
            outputFilename = "extracted/" + name
            print "Saving extracted file to ",outputFilename
            output = open(outputFilename,'wb')
            output.write(uncompressed)
            output.close()

            # send data via tcp stream

            # file successfully downloaded and extracted store into local log and filesystem log
            downloadedLog[url] = time.time();
            pickle.dump(downloadedLog, open('downloaded.pickle', "wb" ))
```

Comment: ZIP format isn't designed to be streamed. It uses footers, meaning you need the *end* of the file to figure out where things belong inside it, meaning you need to have the whole file before you can do anything with a subset of it.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) object. They emulate files, but reside in memory. So you could do something like this:

```
# get_zip_data() gets a zip archive containing 'foo.txt', reading 'hey, foo'

import zipfile
from StringIO import StringIO

zipdata = StringIO()
zipdata.write(get_zip_data())
myzipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipdata)
foofile = myzipfile.open('foo.txt')
print foofile.read()

# output: "hey, foo"
```

Or more simply (apologies to Vishal):

```
myzipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO(get_zip_data()))
for name in myzipfile.namelist():
    [ ... ]
```

In Python 3 use BytesIO instead of StringIO:

```
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

filebytes = BytesIO(get_zip_data())
myzipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes)
for name in myzipfile.namelist():
    [ ... ]
```

Comment: "The StringIO object can accept either Unicode or 8-bit strings" Doesn't this mean that if the number of bytes you expect to write is not congruent to 0 mod 8, then you will either throw an exception or write incorrect data?

Comment: Not at all -- why would you only be able to write 8 bytes at a time? Conversely, when do you ever write fewer than 8 bits at a time?

Comment: @ninjagecko: You seem to fear a problem if the number of bytes expected to be written is not a multiple of 8. That is not derivable from the statement about StringIO and is quite baseless. The problem with StringIO is when the user **mixes** `unicode` objects with `str` objects that are not decodable by the system default encoding (which is typically `ascii`).

Comment: Small comment on the above code: when you read multiple files out of the .zip, make sure you read the data out one by one, because calling zipfile.open two times will remove the reference in the first.

Comment: Notice that as of Python 3 you have to use `from io import StringIO`

Comment: @senderle how do you save the file you downloaded?

Comment: What do you mean by "`get_zip_data()` gets a zip archive"? What type of object does it return? How does it get it?

Answer (score 114):

Below is a code snippet I used to fetch zipped csv file, please have a look:

**Python 2**:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib import urlopen

resp = urlopen("http://www.test.com/file.zip")
myzip = ZipFile(StringIO(resp.read()))
for line in myzip.open(file).readlines():
    print line
```

**Python 3**:

```
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen
# or: requests.get(url).content

resp = urlopen("http://www.test.com/file.zip")
myzip = ZipFile(BytesIO(resp.read()))
for line in myzip.open(file).readlines():
    print(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

Here `file` is a string.  To get the actual string that you want to pass, you can use `zipfile.namelist()`.  For instance,

```
resp = urlopen('http://mlg.ucd.ie/files/datasets/bbc.zip')
myzip = ZipFile(BytesIO(resp.read()))
myzip.namelist()
# ['bbc.classes', 'bbc.docs', 'bbc.mtx', 'bbc.terms']
```

Comment: Note  it's a bit confusing to use the same name for a class instances and a library - the identifier `zipfile` gets redefined in this code.

Comment: I just fixed that :)

Comment: When I do `resp = urlopen('http://mlg.ucd.ie/files/datasets/bbc.zip')`, I get `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable`.

Answer (score 34):

I'd like to offer an updated Python 3 version of Vishal's excellent answer, which was using Python 2, along with some explanation of the adaptations / changes, which may have been already mentioned.

```
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib.request
    
url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/locode/loc162txt.zip")

with ZipFile(BytesIO(url.read())) as my_zip_file:
    for contained_file in my_zip_file.namelist():
        # with open(("unzipped_and_read_" + contained_file + ".file"), "wb") as output:
        for line in my_zip_file.open(contained_file).readlines():
            print(line)
            # output.write(line)
```

Necessary changes:

- There's no [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) module in Python 3 (it's been moved to `io.StringIO`). Instead, I use `io.BytesIO`][2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), because we will be handling a bytestream -- [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html), also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064981/python3-error-initial-value-must-be-str-or-none).
- urlopen:

  - "The legacy `urllib.urlopen` function from Python 2.6 and earlier has been discontinued; [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) corresponds to the old `urllib2.urlopen`.",  [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042152/python-3-5-1-urllib-has-no-attribute-request).

Note:

- In Python 3, the printed output lines will look like so: `b'some text'`. This is expected, as they aren't strings - remember, we're reading a bytestream. Have a look at [Dan04's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal).

A few minor changes I made:

- I use `with ... as` instead of `zipfile = ...` according to [the Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).
- The script now uses [`.namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) to cycle through all the files in the zip and print their contents.
- I moved the creation of the [`ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) object into the `with` statement, although I'm not sure if that's better.
- I added (and commented out) an option to write the bytestream to file (per file in the zip), in response to NumenorForLife's comment; it adds `"unzipped_and_read_"` to the beginning of the filename and a `".file"` extension (I prefer not to use `".txt"` for files with bytestrings). The indenting of the code will, of course, need to be adjusted if you want to use it.

  - Need to be careful here -- because we have a byte string, we use binary mode, so `"wb"`; I have a feeling that writing binary opens a can of worms anyway...
- I am using an example file, the [UN/LOCODE text archive](http://www.unece.org/cefact/codesfortrade/codes_index.html):

What I didn't do:

- NumenorForLife asked about saving the zip to disk. I'm not sure what he meant by it -- downloading the zip file? That's a different task; see [Oleh Prypin's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3).

Here's a way:

```
import urllib.request
import shutil

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/locode/2015-2_UNLOCODE_SecretariatNotes.pdf") as response, open("downloaded_file.pdf", 'w') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

Comment: If you want to write all the files to disk the easier way is to use my_zip_file.extractall('my_target')` instead of looping. But that's great!

Comment: can you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417455/aws-lambda-read-zip-file-perform-validation-and-unzip-to-s3-bucket-if-validation

Answer (score 27):

I'd like to add my Python3 answer for completeness:

```
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
import requests

def get_zip(file_url):
    url = requests.get(file_url)
    zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(url.content))
    files = [zipfile.open(file_name) for file_name in zipfile.namelist()]
    return files.pop() if len(files) == 1 else files
```

Comment: Could you please expand a bit on what exactly this function returns and how to go forward with the returned data? Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

write to a temporary file which resides in RAM

it turns out the `tempfile` module ( http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html ) has just the thing:

> tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile([max_size=0[,
>   mode='w+b'[, bufsize=-1[, suffix=''[,
>   prefix='tmp'[, dir=None]]]]]])
>
> This
>   function operates exactly as
>   TemporaryFile() does, except that data
>   is spooled in memory until the file
>   size exceeds max_size, or until the
>   file’s fileno() method is called, at
>   which point the contents are written
>   to disk and operation proceeds as with
>   TemporaryFile().
>
> The resulting file has one additional
>   method, rollover(), which causes the
>   file to roll over to an on-disk file
>   regardless of its size.
>
> The returned object is a file-like
>   object whose _file attribute is either
>   a StringIO object or a true file
>   object, depending on whether
>   rollover() has been called. This
>   file-like object can be used in a with
>   statement, just like a normal file.
>
> New in version 2.6.

or if you're lazy and you have a tmpfs-mounted `/tmp` on Linux, you can just make a file there, but you have to delete it yourself and deal with naming

Comment: +1 -- didn't know about SpooledTemporaryFile. My inclination would still be to use StringIO explicitly, but this is good to know.

Answer (score 15):

Adding on to the other answers using **requests**:

```
 # download from web

 import requests
 url = 'http://mlg.ucd.ie/files/datasets/bbc.zip'
 content = requests.get(url)

 # unzip the content
 from io import BytesIO
 from zipfile import ZipFile
 f = ZipFile(BytesIO(content.content))
 print(f.namelist())

 # outputs ['bbc.classes', 'bbc.docs', 'bbc.mtx', 'bbc.terms']
```

Use **help(f)** to get more functions details for e.g. **extractall()** which extracts the contents in zip file which later can be used with **with open**.

Comment: To read your CSV, do: `with f.open(f.namelist()[0], 'r') as g:     df = pd.read_csv(g)`

Answer (score 8):

All of these answers appear too bulky and long. Use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/) to shorten the code, e.g.:

```py
import requests, zipfile, io
r = requests.get(zip_file_url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall("/path/to/directory")
```

Answer (score 4):

Vishal's example, however great, confuses when it comes to the file name, and I do not see the merit of redefing 'zipfile'.

Here is my example that downloads a zip that contains some files, one of which is a csv file that I subsequently read into a pandas DataFrame:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib import urlopen
import pandas

url = urlopen("https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/mdrm/pdf/MDRM.zip")
zf = ZipFile(StringIO(url.read()))
for item in zf.namelist():
    print("File in zip: "+  item)
# find the first matching csv file in the zip:
match = [s for s in zf.namelist() if ".csv" in s][0]
# the first line of the file contains a string - that line shall de ignored, hence skiprows
df = pandas.read_csv(zf.open(match), low_memory=False, skiprows=[0])
```

(Note, I use Python 2.7.13)

This is the exact solution that worked for me. I just tweaked it a little bit for Python 3 version by removing StringIO and adding IO library

## Python 3 Version

```
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas
import requests

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/indices/mcwb_jun19.zip"
content = requests.get(url)
zf = ZipFile(BytesIO(content.content))

for item in zf.namelist():
    print("File in zip: "+  item)

# find the first matching csv file in the zip:
match = [s for s in zf.namelist() if ".csv" in s][0]
# the first line of the file contains a string - that line shall de     ignored, hence skiprows
df = pandas.read_csv(zf.open(match), low_memory=False, skiprows=[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't obvious in Vishal's answer what the file name was supposed to be in cases where there is no file on disk. I've modified his answer to work without modification for most needs.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib import urlopen

def unzip_string(zipped_string):
    unzipped_string = ''
    zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(zipped_string))
    for name in zipfile.namelist():
        unzipped_string += zipfile.open(name).read()
    return unzipped_string
```

Comment: This is a Python 2 answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module. To extract a file from a URL, you'll need to wrap the result of a [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) call in a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object. This is because the result of a web request returned by `urlopen` doesn't support seeking:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip_url = 'http://example.com/my_file.zip'

with urlopen(zip_url) as f:
    with BytesIO(f.read()) as b, ZipFile(b) as myzipfile:
        foofile = myzipfile.open('foo.txt')
        print(foofile.read())
```

If you already have the file downloaded locally, you don't need `BytesIO`, just open it in binary mode and pass to `ZipFile` directly:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip_filename = 'my_file.zip'

with open(zip_filename, 'rb') as f:
    with ZipFile(f) as myzipfile:
        foofile = myzipfile.open('foo.txt')
        print(foofile.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Again, note that you have to `open` the file in [binary (`'rb'`) mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), not as text or you'll get a `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` error.

It's good practice to use all these things as context managers with the `with` statement, so that they'll be closed properly.