# Download file from web in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program that will download a .jar (java) file from a web server, by reading the URL that is specified in the .jad file of the same game/application. I'm using Python 3.2.1

I've managed to extract the URL of the JAR file from the JAD file (every JAD file contains the URL to the JAR file), but as you may imagine, the extracted value is type() string.

Here's the relevant function:

```
def downloadFile(URL=None):
    import httplib2
    h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
    resp, content = h.request(URL, "GET")
    return content

downloadFile(URL_from_file)
```

However I always get an error saying that the type in the function above has to be bytes, and not string. I've tried using the URL.encode('utf-8'), and also bytes(URL,encoding='utf-8'), but I'd always get the same or similar error.

So basically my question is how to download a file from a server when the URL is stored in a string type?

Comment: @alvas, A bounty for this? The answerer is still (and quite) active on SO. Why not just add a comment and ask?

Comment: Cos a good answer that lasts the test of time is worth awarding. Also, we should start doing this for a lot of other questions to check whether answers are relevant today. Especially when the sorting of SO answers are rather crazy, sometimes the out-dated or even worst answer goes to the top.

Answer (score 826, accepted):

If you want to obtain the contents of a web page into a variable, just `read` the response of [**`urllib.request.urlopen`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

```
import urllib.request
...
url = 'http://example.com/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()      # a `bytes` object
text = data.decode('utf-8') # a `str`; this step can't be used if data is binary
```

---

The easiest way to download and save a file is to use the [**`urllib.request.urlretrieve`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) function:

```
import urllib.request
...
# Download the file from `url` and save it locally under `file_name`:
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
```

```
import urllib.request
...
# Download the file from `url`, save it in a temporary directory and get the
# path to it (e.g. '/tmp/tmpb48zma.txt') in the `file_name` variable:
file_name, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
```

But keep in mind that `urlretrieve` is considered [legacy](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface) and might become deprecated (not sure why, though).

So the most *correct* way to do this would be to use the [**`urllib.request.urlopen`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) function to return a file-like object that represents an HTTP response and copy it to a real file using [**`shutil.copyfileobj`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj).

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
...
# Download the file from `url` and save it locally under `file_name`:
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

If this seems too complicated, you may want to go simpler and store the whole download in a `bytes` object and then write it to a file. But this works well only for small files.

```
import urllib.request
...
# Download the file from `url` and save it locally under `file_name`:
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    data = response.read() # a `bytes` object
    out_file.write(data)
```

---

It is possible to extract `.gz` (and maybe other formats) compressed data on the fly, but such an operation probably requires the HTTP server to support random access to the file.

```
import urllib.request
import gzip
...
# Read the first 64 bytes of the file inside the .gz archive located at `url`
url = 'http://example.com/something.gz'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response) as uncompressed:
        file_header = uncompressed.read(64) # a `bytes` object
        # Or do anything shown above using `uncompressed` instead of `response`.
```

Comment: you could use `response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf-8')` instead of hardcoding `utf-8`, to get the character encoding from `Content-Type` header

Comment: @OlehPrypin Why does `outfile.write(data)` only work well for small files?

Comment: "urlretrieve is considered legacy and might become deprecated"  where did you get that idea?

Comment: @Corey: Right from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface): "21.6.24. Legacy interface
The following functions and classes are ported from the Python 2 module urllib (as opposed to urllib2). They might become deprecated at some point in the future." ...and I agree on Oleh's "not sure why"

Comment: @Oleh Prypin if I use with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file: shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file) then how can I find the HTTP status code in the catch statement to know the file wasn't found?

Comment: What happens when there's a HTTP error in the middle of reading a big file? We get a truncated file and some exception is thrown, right? Seems like `urlopen()` raises `URLError` but what is raised in the reading phase?

Comment: What would the file size have to reach to be considered not a small file anymore?

Comment: Note that `urlretrieve()` does not support timeout option, while `urlopen()` variant does.

Comment: more examples can be seen here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls

Comment: Is there a way to add a progress bar?

Answer (score 201):

I use `requests` package whenever I want something related to HTTP requests because its API is very easy to start with:

first, install `requests`

```
$ pip install requests
```

then the code:

```
from requests import get  # to make GET request


def download(url, file_name):
    # open in binary mode
    with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
        # get request
        response = get(url)
        # write to file
        file.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 26):

I hope I understood the question right, which is:  how to download a file from a server when the URL is stored in a string type?

I download files and save it locally using the below code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png'
fileName = 'D:\Python\dwnldPythonLogo.png'
req = requests.get(url)
file = open(fileName, 'wb')
for chunk in req.iter_content(100000):
    file.write(chunk)
file.close()
```

Comment: hi, i am also using same type of code for downloading file but some time i have facing exception like - 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010c'..... can you help me with that

Answer (score 20):

You can use **wget** which is popular downloading shell tool for that. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget
This will be the simplest method since it does not need to open up the destination file. Here is an example.

```
import wget
url = 'https://i1.wp.com/python3.codes/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Python3-powered.png?fit=650%2C350'  
wget.download(url, '/Users/scott/Downloads/cat4.jpg')
```

Answer (score 19):

Here we can use urllib's Legacy interface in Python3:

The following functions and classes are ported from the Python 2 module urllib (as opposed to urllib2). They might become deprecated at some point in the future.

Example **(2 lines code)**:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "logo.png")
```

Comment: Is there any reason for such a function to become deprecated? Is there any alternative to this except manually writing the response to a file?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, definietly requests is  great package to use in something related to HTTP requests. but we need to be careful with the encoding type of the incoming data as well below is an example which explains the difference

```
from requests import get

# case when the response is byte array
url = 'some_image_url'

response = get(url)
with open('output', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)


# case when the response is text
# Here unlikely if the reponse content is of type **iso-8859-1** we will have to override the response encoding
url = 'some_page_url'

response = get(url)
# override encoding by real educated guess as provided by chardet
r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding

with open('output', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: The beginner friendliest method I saw so far.

Answer (score 0):

## Motivation

Sometimes, we are want to get the picture but not need to download it to real files,

i.e., **download the data and keep it on memory.**

For example, If I use the machine learning method, train a model that can recognize an image with the number (bar code).

When I spider some websites and that have those images so I can use the model to recognize it,

and I don't want to save those pictures on my disk drive,

then you can try the below method to help you keep download data on memory.

## Points

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
response = requests.get(url)
with BytesIO as io_obj:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        io_obj.write(chunk)
```

basically, is like to @Ranvijay Kumar

## An Example

```
import requests
from typing import NewType, TypeVar
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio

URL = NewType('URL', str)
T_IO = TypeVar('T_IO', StringIO, BytesIO)


def download_and_keep_on_memory(url: URL, headers=None, timeout=None, **option) -> T_IO:
    chunk_size = option.get('chunk_size', 4096)  # default 4KB
    max_size = 1024 ** 2 * option.get('max_size', -1)  # MB, default will ignore.
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise requests.ConnectionError(f'{response.status_code}')

    instance_io = StringIO if isinstance(next(response.iter_content(chunk_size=1)), str) else BytesIO
    io_obj = instance_io()
    cur_size = 0
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
        cur_size += chunk_size
        if 0 < max_size < cur_size:
            break
        io_obj.write(chunk)
    io_obj.seek(0)
    """ save it to real file.
    with open('temp.png', mode='wb') as out_f:
        out_f.write(io_obj.read())
    """
    return io_obj


def main():
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'zh-TW,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Host': 'statics.591.com.tw',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36'
    }
    io_img = download_and_keep_on_memory(URL('http://statics.591.com.tw/tools/showPhone.php?info_data=rLsGZe4U%2FbphHOimi2PT%2FhxTPqI&type=rLEFMu4XrrpgEw'),
                                         headers,  # You may need this. Otherwise, some websites will send the 404 error to you.
                                         max_size=4)  # max loading < 4MB
    with io_img:
        plt.rc('axes.spines', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
        plt.rc(('xtick', 'ytick'), color=(1, 1, 1, 0))  # same of plt.axis('off')
        plt.imshow(imageio.imread(io_img, as_gray=False, pilmode="RGB"))
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from urllib import request

def get(url):
    with request.urlopen(url) as r:
        return r.read()


def download(url, file=None):
    if not file:
        file = url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(get(url))
```

Answer (score -7):

If you are using Linux you can use the `wget` module of Linux through the python shell. Here is a sample code snippet

```
import os
url = 'http://www.example.com/foo.zip'
os.system('wget %s'%url)
```

Comment: This is one of the worst examples i've ever seen of introducing an injection attack into a system. os.system combined with a string format with no checking.