# How to download a file using Python

Tags: python, download

I tried to download something from the Internet using Python, I am using `urllib.retriever` from the urllib module but I just can't get it work. I would like to be able to save the downloaded file to a location of my choice.
If someone could explain to me how to do it with clear examples, that would be VERY appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file from web in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) like so:

```
source = urllib2.urlopen("http://someUrl.com/somePage.html").read()
open("/path/to/someFile", "wb").write(source)
```

You could even shorten it to (although, you wouldnt want to shorten it if you plan to enclose each individual call in a `try` - `except`):

```
open("/path/to/someFile", "wb").write(urllib2.urlopen("http://someUrl.com/somePage.html").read())
```

Comment: You might consider using `"wb"` rather than `"w"` in case the downloaded file is binary.

Comment: Thanks it working very well, now I just have to understand why exactly. =)

Comment: @user which part doesnt make sense?  Ill try to explain more if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the urllib:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen(("full_url")).read()
```

and then use what chown used above:

```
open("/path/to/someFile", "wb").write(source)
```