# How do I download a file using urllib.request in Python 3?

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, urllib

So, I'm messing around with `urllib.request` in Python 3 and am wondering how to write the result of getting an internet file to a file on the local machine. I tried this:

```
g = urllib.request.urlopen('http://media-mcw.cursecdn.com/3/3f/Beta.png')
with open('test.png', 'b+w') as f:
    f.write(g)
```

But I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'HTTPResponse' does not support the buffer interface
```

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116623/how-to-download-a-file-using-python), but it's related to Python 2's `urllib2` which was overhauled in Python 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file from web in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change

```
f.write(g)
```

to

```
f.write(g.read())
```

Answer (score 7):

An easier way I think (also you can do it in two lines) is to use:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://media-mcw.cursecdn.com/3/3f/Beta.png', 'test.png')
```

As for the method you have used.  When you use `g = urllib.request.urlopen('http://media-mcw.cursecdn.com/3/3f/Beta.png')` you are just fetching the file.  You must use `g.read()`, `g.readlines()` or `g.readline()` to read it it.

It's just like reading a normal file (except for the syntax) and can be treated in a very similar way.

Comment: The `PEP20` would have you use `Request` from `urllib.request` but yours would have a line less of code. [Information about PEP20 for Request](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html). You can use `open()` chained to `file.write(url.read())` like you mentioned.

Comment: @Debug255 Are you sure?  The link mentioned `Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a Request object.`, here I specified a string so I don't think Request is required in this case.

Comment: That worked on debian9 using python3.5. I don't use 2.7 too much.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have to get round the `403: Forbidden` issue using https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187955/563247

Comment: @Sevenearths That's true.  However that's a different issue.  Out of all the files  I have used python to download/read, only a handful have ever given me a 403 error.  I don't think this is a big enough reason not to warrent the use of `urlretrieve()`.  Obviously if that issue is encounted, then what you have linked is the way forward

Comment: Interesting how experiences differ. While writing my app the **first** url I tried `https://medium.com/@tomaspueyo/coronavirus-the-hammer-and-the-dance-be9337092b56` and it gave me the `403: Forbidden`. I wonder if it's just a Medium related issue

Comment: @Sevenearths 403 is a Forbidden error.  This usually happens when a website (server) attempts to block a bot.  Or you try to access a webpage with incorrect login/cert information (usually cookie related from my experience, like passing outdated information, or similar).  Seen as the solution you listed uses a user agent, it strongly looks like that site attepts to block bots (which makes sense since it's a news site) a user agent tricks the server into thinking it's a legitimate browser.

Comment: @Sevenearths Personally I usually use dedicated APIs (and this sort of thing never comes up, as they expect bots), which is probably why I don't encounter the problem much.