# Making/download a csv file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, csv, urllib2

I want to make a CSV with the Closed values of stocks, by downloading them from Yahoo Finance using python 2.7 on Windows. The file is call "Historical Prices". I have the tickers in a list and i want to know if I can make a csv file with the closed values in a row. For example:

```
AAPL,109,87,110.06,
GOOG,2123.546,213,56,
```

(and so on)

So far my script is this:

```
import urllib2
import csv

nasdaqlisted = urllib2.urlopen("ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt")
raw = nasdaqlisted.read().split("\r\n")
del raw[0]
del raw[-1]

tickerslist = []
for l in raw:
    linea = l.split("|")
    tickerslist.append(linea[0])
del tickerslist[-1]

def closed(tickerslist):
    url = urllib2.urlopen("http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" +tickerslist+ "&d=8&e=13&f=2014&g=d&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv")
    raw = url.read().split("\r\n")
    del raw[0]
    del raw[-1]

closed_us = open("closed-us.csv","w")

for i in tickerslist:
    cierres.write(closed(i))
closed_us.close()
```

Thank you very much!

P.D.: I found a this question. It may help you [Download a .csv file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500918/download-a-csv-file-with-python) but I doesn't work saying that is because "request" can not be be import (I guess is because I use python 2.7 instead of 3.3)

Comment: It is `from urllib2 import urlopen`; otherwise the code in the post you found works just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have looks good.
For CSV file, generally, it's simple enough just to write a normal text files an put commas where needed - no need for anything fansy.  In your example:

```
def closed(tickerslist):
    returnLine = tickerslist
    url = urllib2.urlopen("http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" +tickerslist+ "&d=8&e=13&f=2014&g=d&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv")
    raw = url.read().split("\r\n")[1:-1]
    # if you wanted to grab the last number on each line...
    for line in raw:
        returnLine += ','+line[line.rfind(',')+1:])
    return returnLine+'\n'
```

If you're interested in only a small portion of a file, the 'read' method has an optional parameter for bytes to read.  So you don't have to download the whole file to find something at the beginning.  This parameter is also helpful if you wanted to download a larger file in a separate thread and update the main thread (usually a gui) about the progress.

Hope this helps.