# urllib.request for python 3.3 not working to download file

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

I would like to download a large archive file with python and save it, but urllib is not working for me. This is my code:

```
    import urllib
    urllib.request("http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/particle_tutorial_7.txt")
```

Note that the link I used in this example is not a large archive. I am only using it as an example. It links directly to a .txt file, so it should work. I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib.request("http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/particle_tutorial_7.txt")
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

It seems to me like urllib is somehow broken and missing the "request" method. I am using Python 3.3. Should I be using another module or is it actually a Python problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file from web in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is not broken.  [The `urllib.request` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html) is pretty clear on how this works:

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
data = req.read()
```

**Edit:** If you need to write the file directly to disk rather than process the data, use `urlretrieve`.

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://example.com/big.zip', 'file/on/disk.zip')
```

Comment: Note: *"I would like to download a large archive file with python and save it"*. `req.read()` is not appropriate if you want to download a large file that might not fit in memory. You could use [`urlretrieve()`  instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20716205/4279)

Comment: `urlretrieve` *might become deprecated at some point in the future* according to the manual. Is there a future-safe way of saving directly to a file?

Answer (score 4):

To download an url into a file, you could use [`urlretrieve()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request#urllib.request.urlretrieve):

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
url = "http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/particle_tutorial_7.txt"
urlretrieve(url, "result.txt")
```

Comment: `urlretrieve` is a legacy implementation and *might become deprecated* in future versions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface

Comment: @ccpizza: I've been seeing the warning for almost 10 years and the wording is the same: "might become deprecated" that is not the same thing as "the function is deprecated".  `urlretrieve()` is just a convenience function, a  wrapper around `urlopen()`. If it works for you, no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I've found that it doesn't work when specific headers need to be set since the api doesn't allow setting custom headers, e.g. `user-agent`.

Answer (score 1):

The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3.0 named urllib.request and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to 3

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = urlopen(r"http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/particle_tutorial_7.txt")

print(data)
```