# Compatibility issue using python script

Tags: python, compatibility

I have to download McAfee virus definition update file and then execute it. If I download it directrly from site using Windows download/save ... it works fine.
In my case I do it using python script from http://download.nai.com/products/licensed/superdat/english/intel/
When I try to execute the file downloaded using script it failed with this error:

```
>7615xdat.exe
This version of N:\DeleteMe\deleteMePlease\7615xdat.exe is not compatible with the version of
Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86
 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
```

I noticed that while both files have the same name they are different in size ( the one downloaded using script is slightly bigger), they have also different icon in windows explorer.
I assume that python script does not make 'exact' copy of the file from web which result into the error.
Any idea how to fix it?
I will attach the script I am using:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
import os
import shutil

# index page
pattern_files_url = "http://download.nai.com/products/licensed/superdat/english/intel"
# relative url references based here
pattern_files_base = '/'.join(pattern_files_url.split('/')[:-1])

# scrape the index page for latest file list
doc = lxml.html.parse(pattern_files_url)
pattern_files = [ref for ref in doc.xpath("//a/@href") if ref.endswith('xdat.exe')]
if pattern_files:
    pattern_files.sort()
    newest = pattern_files[-1]
    local_name = newest.split('/')[-1]
    # grab it if we don't already have it
    if not os.path.exists(local_name):
        url = pattern_files_base + '/' + newest
        remote = urllib.urlopen(url)
        with open(local_name, 'w') as local:
            shutil.copyfileobj(remote, local, length=65536)
```

Comment: It should download it exactly the same. But perhaps the website is doing browser sniffing and giving you a different file based on the user agent of url lib ?

Comment: It could be typical x86 and x64 issue. What architecture of WIndows OS you are running now?

Comment: @Doon checking on the download link, it is just a file hosting which does not look like doing any different files based on UA.

Comment: You're not opening the output file in binary mode. Use `open(local_name, 'wb')` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file from web in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Comment: thanks for reply ... but how could I fix it?

Comment: I'm running Win 7 Professional 64  bit

Comment: - Lukas Graf
Thanks a lot, the issue was with 'wb', I am all set now!! 
You made my day.