# how to make file downloader like idm using php

Tags: php, download

i want to make a file downloader like wget using php. how can i make this downloader which will download file to my local machine. i have been made this download using file_get_contents() function. This is my code

```
$raw = file_get_contents($_url);
file_put_contents($_dir, $raw);
```

But i have seen so many solutions in which they are used curl. but i wan't familiar in curl so i have using file_get_contents() function. is there any other functions which are easy and works more better than file_get_contents().

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should get these urls of songs into list. I do not know what is the structure of your file, but reading files in Python is pretty easy.

To download files I would use `urllib` library. Here is sample:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve

songsList = ['http://example.com/song1.mp3', 'http://example.com/song2.mp3']

for song in songsList:
    urlretrieve(song, song.split('/')[-1])
```

Where `songsList` is your list with urls to download.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making a python program that will read the URL's from the list so that they are contained as strings in python. 
Then you will need to import the [urllib.request.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) into python,([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)) to download the files to the machine. 
As far as making this run whenever ON and connected to the internet, you would need an if/else statement that can check for internet connection.

This is just a starting point, and it would be helpful to know what you have already begun.