# How to write a large binary file from the internet in python 3 without reading the entire file to memory?

Tags: python

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3) provides a very helpful way to download a file from the internet using Python 3.

Essentially it says to use:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

if the `url` specifies a huge file, isn't the `response` automatically stored in memory?  I.e. even though `copyfileobj` buffers the file, doesn't just making the request return the entire large file as `response`?

Comment: "doesn't just making the request return the entire large file as `response`" By the way, you could ask a similar question "doesn't calling `with open("bigfile.txt", "r") as response` read the entire large file into memory as `response`?". The answer to that question is also "no", and for reasons that in some respects are similar to the case for a response object from `urllib` and in other respects different. It's worth looking in more detail into how different types of I/O work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `urlopen` will return a file like object over a socket. Quoting:

> Open a network object denoted by a URL for reading. If the URL does not 
>   have a scheme identifier, or if it has file: as its scheme identifier, 
>   this opens a local file (without universal newlines); otherwise it 
>   opens a socket to a server somewhere on the network. If the connection 
>   cannot be made the IOError exception is raised. If all went well, a 
>   file-like object is returned. This supports the following methods: 
>   read(), readline(), readlines(), fileno(), close(), info(), getcode() and geturl().

So since `seek` method is not supported either by urlopen but not also used by `copyfileobj` we can deduce that there is no need to store all the content in memory.

Comment: So `seek` can only be used on  objects in memory and if it is not available than the object is not in memory? As @SteveJessop mentioned in his comment to my question, I could seek around `with open("bigfile.txt", "r")` without reading it all into memory no?

Comment: Seeking in real files doesn't read them all in memory. What I meant is without seek a file like object is used for streaming. And when you stream content there is no good reason to store it all in memory, just buffer it.