# PyCharm ImportError

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, importerror

New to Python3.5 (and MacOS) and have begun by using the PyCharm IDE.  I'm using an example from [Download file from web in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3) to download a file, but it fails at the first statement:

```
import urllib.request 
url = 'http://example.com/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()      # a `bytes` object
text = data.decode('utf-8')


/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5      /Users/nevd/PycharmProjects/py3/download.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nevd/PycharmProjects/py3/download.py", line 4, in <module>
  import urllib.request
  File "/Users/nevd/PycharmProjects/py3/urllib.py", line 9, in <module>
   import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package
```

However the code works OK from Terminal, so I assume the problem is a PyCharm configuration issue.  Under `PyCharm File>Default Settings>Default Project>Project Interpreter` the project interpreter is 3.5.0 but below that I only see 2 Packages: `pip 7.1.2` & `setuptools 18.2`.

Mac OS X v10.11.1 (El Capitan) and PyCharm Community 5.0.1

Comment: I guess name of your file is urllib.py

Comment: Good guess, thankyou Prashant fixed now.

Comment: I've further explained this below in my answer , if it worked you might wanna mark it accepted. Happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything just rename your file from urllib.py to something else in this case you are overshadowing your library package which you are adding to the file.

> Rename your file