# Download a file from https with authentication

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.6

I have a Python 2.6 script that downloades a file from a web server. I want this this script to pass a username and password(for authenrication before fetching the file) and I am passing them as part of the url as follows:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://'user1':'password'@server_name/file")
```

However, I am getting syntax error in this case. Is this the correct way to go about it? I am pretty new to Python and coding in general.
Can anybody help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: How is the server expecting them? Go to the url and with the network tab open in dev tools log in and see what the request looks like

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#id6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to pass through a Basic Authentication. In this case, you can handle it this way:

```
import urllib2

username = 'user1'
password = '123456'

#This should be the base url you wanted to access.
baseurl = 'http://server_name.com'

#Create a password manager
manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
manager.add_password(None, baseurl, username, password)

#Create an authentication handler using the password manager
auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(manager)

#Create an opener that will replace the default urlopen method on further calls
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

#Here you should access the full url you wanted to open
response = urllib2.urlopen(baseurl + "/file")
```

Comment: how to save the download data in an specific file?

Comment: @Estefy see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244263/5506988

Comment: Do you have an updated one for python 3? Urrlib2 cannot be used in Python 3

Answer (score 19):

If you can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/) library, it's insanely easy. I'd highly recommend using it if possible:

```
import requests

url = 'http://somewebsite.org'
user, password = 'bob', 'I love cats'
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
```

Comment: `request.get` did not work for me in the last line. I guess it should be corrected to `requests.get` with an 's'

Answer (score 0):

Use requests library and just put the credentials inside your .netrc file.

The library will load them from there and you will be able to commit the code to your SCM of choice without any security worries.

Comment: Just to clarify: don't commit your .netrc file, just your code