# how to download PDF with Python or selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I am trying to download a PDF file. The file is opened in browser's PDF viewer. Is accessible only when session is active. Here is what I am trying.

```
def download_pdf(pdf_url):
     local_filename = "myfile.pdf"
     # URL to login
     login_url = 'https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/sajcas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fesaj.tjsp.jus.br%2Fesaj%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check'
     s = requests.Session()
     s.auth = ('33945867894', '******')
     # logs in successfully Status Code = 200 OK
     s.post(login_url, verify=False)
     # Accessing PDF [URL][1] ( getting with selenium) 
     # Fails to get PDF, Staus Code = 401 ( Unauthorized)
     r = s.get(pdf_url,  stream=True, verify=False)
     with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                # f.flush() 
return local_filename
```

I fail to download [PDF](https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/pastadigital/abrirDocumentoEdt.do?nuProcesso=0015348-83.2012.8.26.0278&cdProcesso=7QZX9WGZ80000&cdForo=278&baseIndice=INDDS&nmAlias=PG5SBCDS&tpOrigem=2&flOrigem=P&cdServico=190101&ticket=MX0UHU9QI3xhDMraFDVa7so7DbaRQP0ciU9v3jTQY9CCy4IUZbNOKN4F0xYudKlvi6MZYmkSvVI2xzHyGfYBn301dlp92%2BGHI0iHgKWVoS2vkQg%2Fd2Uzp%2BGny%2BKR%2BYOwE4ZYwx65w7OX4pS93VVORsBZpiHhBJhukReAZVN0TXLT5xLC%2Bl7YWqFsBQcY0A4oEGzkiAoDvOIQ60WtuPPjX5coLnnMxm6XXFwiy3ilwXjrjYQrVx0CI4G%2BDGaHaMH1m6d907XaJiwUHDBQ7U8qSAf%2FGxMyrEEtbpOjvpkivyh4GX%2B7VjxqgKXZHsRcgbf2gSAkqZBWy80h0FcCDNvsWw%3D%3D) because of unauthorized access.

**Edit:**
The code which looks up the download link is on the pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/kskmg4Bu

Comment: Try doing a GET on the url first, so the server has a chance to set cookies.

Comment: 1st thing I tried was GET, the same thing.

Comment: If you try to do the same thing in a regular browser, do you get the same error?

Comment: no, in browser it works well.

Comment: Can you give an example for a value of `pdf_url`?

Comment: @Ryan https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/pastadigital/abrirDocumentoEdt.do?nuProcesso=0015348-83.2012.8.26.0278&cdProcesso=7QZX9WGZ80000&cdForo=278&baseIndice=INDDS&nmAlias=PG5SBCDS&tpOrigem=2&flOrigem=P&cdServico=190101&ticket=xv4ji7TxiJGs1yTIlYCUzco7DbaRQP0ciU9v3jTQY9CCy4IUZbNOKN4F0xYudKlvi6MZYmkSvVI2xzHyGfYBn301dlp92%2BGHI0iHgKWVoS2vkQg%2Fd2Uzp%2BGny%2BKR%2BYOwE4ZYwx65w7OX4pS93VVORsBZpiHhBJhukReAZVN0TXLT5xLC%2Bl7YWqFsBQcY0A4oEGzkiAoDvOIQ60WtuPPjX5coLnnMxm6XXFwiy3ilwXjrjYQrVx0CI4G%2BDGaHaMH1m6d907XaJiwUHDBQ7U8qSP4CmO0HU088zwv7aNqLGT9qA8RYSPosTD4HWDE%2BRHjB69QBEE%2F37p0Lp1eEd8CqoQ%3D%3D

Comment: Link doesn't work....

Comment: yes, because it works for active session only

Comment: @Ryan added pastebin which searchs for the URL. https://pastebin.com/kskmg4Bu