# How can I add a header to urllib.request.urlretrieve keeping my variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to download a file from a website but it looks like it is detecting urllib and doesn't allow it to download (I'm getting the error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden").

How can I fix this? I found on the internet that I had to add a header but the answers weren't going the way I need (It was using Request and I didn't find anything about an argument to add in urllib.request.urlretrieve() for a header)

I'm using Python 3.6

Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request
filelink = 'https://randomwebsite.com/changelog.txt'
filename = filelink.rsplit('/', 1)
filename = str(filename[1])
urllib.request.urlretrieve(filelink, filename)
```

I want to include a header to give me the permission to download the file but I need to keep a line like the last one, using the two variables (one for the link of the file and one for the name that depends of the link).

Thanks already for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244263/5903276

The most correct way to do this would be to use the urllib.request.urlopen function to return a file-like object that represents an HTTP response and copy it to a real file using shutil.copyfileobj.