# Downloading image files from websites

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a regular expression which scrapes websites for the image names/sources:
`image` is then displayed like this once iv run the code:

```
[+] 4 images Found:
2018-a-space.JPG
small.jpg
picture.gif
image-certified.jpg
```

I now want to download these images into a folder within the same working directory. I've had a look at some similar questions on here and most recommend using beautifulsoup which i don't want to use. But dont mind importing other modules if they're appropriate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the regex part of your code is working as expected please remove it from the question, because it doesn't seem relevant. The question appears to be simply "Given a list of urls, how do I download them?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file from web in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

No need to read all of that.

Use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library — just install it with `pip requests install` at a command prompt.

You will need the full urls of the images, rather than just the file names, to pass to `requests.get`, as shown here.

In the `open` statement you can probably get away with just a file name, as I have, because you want to store the files in the current working directory. Note that the file must be opened 'wb'.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/AB10/production/_93629734_thinkstockphotos-625798052.jpg'
>>> response = requests.get(url).content
>>> open('squirrel.jpg', 'wb').write(response)
59938
```

This also assumes that the images are not 'too big'. If they are then you should refer to the documentation for further advice about reading them in smaller pieces.