# Import Events from .CAL Calendar

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, import, calendar

I've looked extremely hard but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.
I have a Program that opens a black full-screen window, and I wanted it to display the events of a .cal Calendar with is uploaded by the user publicly on the web.
What I've looked for was, a way for python to "download" the file and extract the Events from it, displaying them as text.
As a final result I'll wish to see all the events on the left.
I've looked for similar programs to reverse engineer and extract the code that would be helpful to me, couldn't succeed tho.
I've seen this from the MagicMirror, but the code is Javascript(I think) and that is not really what I'm familiar with.

Comment: Mention how does the file looks like, what have you tried in python what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two things:

1. [How to download a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3).
2. [How to parse a .cal file](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will see, Thank you a lot!