# Download data from URL in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-requests

I want to download data from https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ln/ln.data.1.AllData to dataframe.

I have tried below script, but could not succeeded.

```
import requests, io
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ln/ln.data.1.AllData'

#1
urlData = requests.get(URL).content
rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(urlData.decode('utf-8')))
print(len(rawData))

Error: Python IDLE Got Stuck


#2
r = requests.get(URL)  
urlData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r))
print(len(urlData))

Error:-
urlData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r))
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not Response

#3
urlData = pd.read_csv(URL, header=None)
print(len(urlData))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Comment: @AlistairCarscadden How is that a duplicate? One question is about using `requests` and feeding the result to `pandas`; the other is about using `httplib2`.

Comment: What does "could not succeeded" mean? What happens? An exception? Then paste the exception here. No error, and `rawData` isn't empty, but doesn't have the results you expected? Then show us what you expected and what you got. If you don't tell us what the problem is, we can't debug it.

Comment: When I run your #1, it takes a long time, but it prints out `6314507`, which seems to be the right answer.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for the reply. In second script I got error "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not Response"

Comment: @SPy Yes, your second script is wrong. But that doesn't change the fact that your first script works.

Comment: @abarnert, I agree... First OK now.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working with

```
import requests, io
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ln/ln.data.1.AllData'

#1
urlData = requests.get(URL).content
rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(urlData.decode('utf-8')), sep="\t")
print(rawData.head())
print(rawData.info())
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to use urllib2.

```
import urllib2
url_name = 'http://abc.pdf'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_name)
file = open(url_name.split('//')[1], 'w')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()
```

Comment: thanks, this also helps for some other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to download the data through the URL, and it does take a very long time. I recommend you to download through `wget` and then process it. The script itself seems fine.