# Command to make files download instead of being displayed

Tags: python, html

I use the following `<meta>` tag to download a file but some files like `pdf` are being viewed instead of getting download.

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="5;{{ filepath }}">
```

How can I alter this statement to make ALL the files download?

And if I was to use a python/bottle framework command to have the same functionality what that command would be e.g. `static_file()`

Comment: couple of options; have a look at the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header, and the `target="_blank"` href parameters

Comment: Please show me in code what you mean ot even better in python code

Comment: I was wondering if i can use the `static_file()` from withing a template as follows: `{{ static_file( filename, root=filepath, download=True ) }}` Can it be written like that? And if can how one can substitite the variables within the statement, in my case `filename` and `filepath` with its values taken from the `.py` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3

Comment: I don;t understand i opened a new thread on this can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570270/passing-a-query-value-from-a-bottle-html-template-to-a-route-with-an-encoding