# Downloading files in Jupyter: wget on Windows?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am trying to download files from a url.

I found `wget` command to be able to do that. Since I use Jupyter, I did not want to use `pip`, however `conda install conda wget` didn't work as there is no Windows `wget` in the default repository. Thus I did `conda install menpo wget` which successfully installed `wget`. However I still cannot import `wget` in JupyterLab:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wget'`

1. Are there any other steps to import `wget`?
2. Is there a better way to download files in Jupyter?

Comment: I still get `No module named 'wget'`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library.  Maybe try [Download file from web in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3) instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As Trenton_M pointed out, there is a `urllib` library that can do it instead of `wget`:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://address'
filename = 'myfile.txt'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Comment: Perfect replacement.

Answer (score 14):

In Google-Collab this code works well:

```
!wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/6319559/preview.mp3 -O sample_f.mp3
!wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/256324900/preview.mp3 -O sample_m.mp3
```

But not locally on Windows 10. In my Jupyter Notebook cell this code:

```
# pip install wget
!python -m wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/6319559/preview.mp3 -o sample_f.mp3
!python -m wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/256324900/preview.mp3 -o sample_m.mp3
```

Saves files and returns:

```
Saved under sample_f.mp3
Saved under sample_m.mp3
```

OR I tried another way: I downloaded **wget.exe** for Windows from [here](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) and moved it to PATH-directory. Then code works too:

```
!wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/6319559/preview.mp3 -O sample_f.mp3
!wget https://audio-previews.elements.envatousercontent.com/files/256324900/preview.mp3 -O sample_m.mp3
```