# How to download zip file from a Hyperlink in python

Tags: python-3.x

there is website with url

https://www.fda.gov/drugs/drug-approvals-and-databases/drugsfda-data-files

and there is one downloadable file

Drugs@FDA Download File (ZIP - 3.2MB)  as Hyperlink in the content of the site.

I have tried the code as below

```py
import urllib.request
import gzip
url = 'https://www.fda.gov/media/89850/download'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response) as uncompressed:
        file_header = uncompressed.read()
```

But i am getting error of : Not a Zipped file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file from web in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Comment: How to get the url of zip file.

Comment: In the webpage how do you download the zip file ? you click the link right? so just copy that link....https://www.fda.gov/media/89850/download

Comment: Hi @ChrisDoyle i have tried the following code ,  but i am getting error, can you please look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the python requests library to get the data from the url then write the contents to a file.

```py
import requests

with open('my_zip_file.zip', 'wb') as my_zip_file:
    data = requests.get('https://www.fda.gov/media/89850/download')
    my_zip_file.write(data.content)
```

This will create a file in the same directory. you can of course name your file anything.