# download from path 'file' save to 'other directory' python script issue

Tags: python, url, save, os.path

Need Help

Get input for where the file is located & tell the new directory to save downloaded URLs to
filepath variable assumes the text document with links is in the location of the python script - while this works, I would also like this to change to direct.

```
    import os.path
    import urllib.request

    # Get one line of text (e.g. C:\user\user\path\directory)

    filepath = input('please input the url file path: ')
    links = open('links.txt', 'r')
    newpath = input('Where would you like to store the file? ')
    for link in links:`
        # then get the filename from the end of the URL
        link = link.strip()
        filename = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

    # Does this file exist in this folder? If not, download it
    if not (os.path.isfile(filename)):
        print ('Downloading: ' + filename + " to " + newpath)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, newpath + filename)
            print ("File size was", os.path.getsize(filename))
        except Exception as inst:
            print (inst)
            print ('  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.')

    # File exists; don't download
    else:
        print("This file exists already.")

# End of program
print("Finished downloading."
```

Comment: Please explain the problem and tell us what you actually want to do. Your current description makes very little sense as to what you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to create a script that takes either a .txt or .xml document ( starting with .txt first as to not over complicate it.) user input where the (.txt) file is located - outside of my python script folder, and direct the program to save the output of the downloaded items from the list to a new folder that relys on user input.

Comment: Ok, doable! What is the issue with the current code, how does it behave?

Comment: "C:\Users\Archie\PycharmProjects\List download test\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
please input the url file path: C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\list
Where would you like to store the file? C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\outputDL
This file exists already.
This file exists already.
This file exists already.
Finished downloading.

Process finished with exit code 0

the files download within the python script folder fine and give me this output ( they are currently in there ) 
the newpath variable doesn't seem to connect
and I'm lost as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is concerning why the `newpath` doesn't seem to connect to it. This is because I believe, in this line of code `urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, newpath + filename)`, the  `link` param doesn't represent anything. You may try and print that value and see what it prints.

Note that `link` in the for loop is a local variable, and anything saved in there will not be accessible anywhere else in the code.

```
for link in links:`
   # then get the filename from the end of the URL
   link = link.strip()
   filename = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

Try defining a global variable named `link` outside the loop so that the value saved in the loop can be preserved to be used everywhere in the code.
Like so,

```
filepath = input('please input the url file path: ')
links = open('links.txt', 'r')
newpath = input('Where would you like to store the file? ')
link = ""
```

Comment: "C:\Users\Archie\PycharmProjects\List download test\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 

please input the url file path: C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\list

Where would you like to store the file? C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\outputDL


Downloading: aardvark_014.jpg to C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\outputDL

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'aardvark_01.jpg'

  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.

Finished downloading.

this is the output I get when I direct it to C:\outputDL, if i leave the first input blank with the list inside the python script folder it downloads correctly.

Comment: Can you replace `print ('Downloading: ' + filename + " to " + newpath)` with this `print ('Downloading: ' + filename + " to " + newpath + " "+  link)` and show me the output plz

Comment: "C:\Users\Archie\PycharmProjects\List download test\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
please input the url file path: C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\list
Where would you like to store the file? C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\outputDL
Downloading: aardvark_thumb.jpg to C:\Users\Archie\Desktop\outputDL https://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/animals/thumbs/rights-exempt/mammals/a/aardvark_thumb.JPG
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'aardvark_thumb.jpg'
  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Archie/PycharmProjects/List download test/Downloadlist.py", line 5, in <module>
    links = open('url.txt', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'url.txt'
# if I change the name of the .txt that's not held in the python library root I get this error this may be where I'm missing critical code?#

Comment: Can you try doing this `urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/animals/thumbs/rights-exempt/mammals/a/aardvark_thumb.JPG")` and see if it works? It may be that its expecting a full url and you're not supplying that. If problems persists, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3) for alternatives

Comment: the problem still persists, I believe the problem is it is not wanting to direct outside of the C:\Users\Archie\PycharmProjects\List download test library. thank you for your help, it was greatly appreciated.