# can't download image with python

Tags: python, imagedownload

try to download images with python
but only this picture can't download it
i don't know the reason cause when i run it, it just stop  just nothing happen
no image , no error code ...

here's the code  plz tell me the reason and solution plz..

```
import urllib.request

num=404

def down(URL):

    fullname=str(num)+"jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL,fullname)
    im="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/67d4aff1-ddd0-4036-a111-3c87ddc0387e.jpg"

down(im)
```

Comment: Did you type your code correctly? `im="https://www...` this part should be out of down fucntion

Comment: ".jpg" maybe you forgot the point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file from web in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Comment: the site you try to download from is blocking get request

Comment: i geuss now it's work i add cookies  and header so avoding to ban ur request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will work for you try to change the url that you use and see result :

```
import requests

pic_url = "https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/67d4aff1-ddd0-4036-a111-3c87ddc0387e.jpg"
cookies = dict(BCPermissionLevel='PERSONAL')


with open('aa.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
        response = requests.get(pic_url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}, cookies=cookies,stream=True)
        if not response.ok:
            print (response)

        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break

            handle.write(block)
```

[image]

Comment: That's not very helpful given the point is to download that specific file, the question is really how to bypass the block you yourself mentioned.

Comment: i update the answer and it's work see now !

Comment: thank you sosoososoooo much your answer is realllllly helpful

Comment: welcome if it help you you can pin it so that will help others too

Comment: hi me again. i have problem with your code can you help me again?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186039/python-auto-image-download-with-as

Answer (score 1):

What @MoetazBrayek says in their comment (but not answer) is correct: the website you're querying is blocking the request.

It's common for sites to block requests based on user-agent or referer: if you try to `curl https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/67d4aff1-ddd0-4036-a111-3c87ddc0387e.jpg` you will get an HTTP error (403 Access Denied):

```
❯ curl -I https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/67d4aff1-ddd0-4036-a111-3c87ddc0387e.jpg
HTTP/2 403
```

Apparently The Sun wants a browser's user-agent, and specifically the string "mozilla" is enough to get through:

```
❯ curl -I -A mozilla https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/67d4aff1-ddd0-4036-a111-3c87ddc0387e.jpg
HTTP/2 200
```

You will have to either switch to the `requests` package or replace your url string with a proper `urllib.request.Request` object so you can customise more pieces of the request. And apparently `urlretrieve` does not support Request objects so you will also have to use `urlopen`:

```py
req = urllib.request.Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'mozilla'})
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
assert res.status == 200
with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
    shutil.copyfileobj(res, out)
```

Comment: No! I am able to visit the webpage. I don't think it is web issue. See my answer. :)

Comment: @Istiak I fear you're just plain wrong. The URL is publicly acceptable, you can try the snippet you suggest and you will see that it doesn't work. However `urlopen(Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'mozilla'}))` will immediately return with a status of 200, and the data.

Comment: publicly *availabie* not acceptable (though it's that as well). You are able to visit the page because your browser sends a browser's user-agent, and the sun filters requests on that basis.