# How to scrape all flag images from website using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, download

Is there a way to get all the flags from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_sovereign_state_flags using python code?

I tried with `pd.read_html` and did not succeed. I tried scraping but it got so messy and I couldn't do it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_sovereign_state_flags")

# Scrap webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
flags = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': "image"})
```

Would be nice if I can download them to a specific folder too!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just as alternative to yours and the well described approach of MattieTK you could also use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select your elements more specific:

```
soup.select('img[src*="/Flag_of"]')
```

Iterate the `ResultSet`, pick the `src` and use a function to download the images:

```
for e in soup.select('img[src*="/Flag_of"]'):
    download_file('https:'+e.get('src'))
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def download_file(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
        with open(file_name,'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                f.write(chunk)
    else:
        print('Image Couldn\'t be retrieved',url)

page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_sovereign_state_flags")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

for e in soup.select('img[src*="/Flag_of"]'):
    download_file('https:'+e.get('src'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `flags` is an array of anchor tags including the `img` tags.

What you want is a way to get each individual `src` attribute from the image tag.

You can achieve this by looping over the results of your `soup.find_all` like so. Each flag is separate, which allows you to get the contents of the flag (the image tag) and then the value of the src attribute.

```
for flag in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': "image"}):
  src = flag.contents[0]['src'])
```

You can then work on [downloading each of these to a file inside the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3).