# Saving a downloaded ZIP file w/Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a script that will automatically update an installed version of Calibre.  Currently I have it downloading the latest portable version.  I seem to be having trouble saving the zipfile. Currently my code is:

```
import urllib2
import re
import zipfile

#tell the user what is happening
print("Calibre is Updating")

#download the page
url = urllib2.urlopen ( "http://sourceforge.net/projects/calibre/files" ).read()

#determin current version
result = re.search('title="/[0-9.]*/([a-zA-Z\-]*-[0-9\.]*)', url).groups()[0][:-1]

#download file
download = "http://status.calibre-ebook.com/dist/portable/" + result
urllib2.urlopen( download )

#save
output = open('install.zip', 'w')
output.write(zipfile.ZipFile("install.zip", ""))
output.close()
```

Comment: Every time I start the download it reports a failure.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Jacobm001: It would be helpful if you provided a short description of what you want and expect your code to do, and include the error message you are getting. It's pretty easy to spot a programming error in your code, but since it's not entirely clear what you want the program to do, it's hard to know if the error is relevant to solving your problem or just a minor detail that is beside the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use `zipfile.ZipFile` for this (and the way you're using it, as well as `urllib2.urlopen`, has problems as well). Instead, you need to save the urlopen result in a variable, then `read` it and write that output to a .zip file. Try this code:

```
#download file
download = "http://status.calibre-ebook.com/dist/portable/" + result
request = urllib2.urlopen( download )

#save
output = open("install.zip", "w")
output.write(request.read())
output.close()
```

Comment: I've tried your method, but I seem to be running into an issue with it.  It downloads the file fine, but when I try to open the completed file it says it's a corrupted file.  Any ideas?

Edit: I've just noticed that the file using your method is just under 200KB larger than the intended zip file.

Comment: I am having the same problem as Jacobm001. Any advise would really be appreciated. The file downloads, but it gives an error when I try to unzip it.

Comment: @user1496289: would it be possible to provide the link to the file so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Would you mind explaining why using ZipFile and urlopen together is a bad idea? This example seems to use both http://stackoverflow.com/a/5711095/2423246

Answer (score 3):

There also can be a one-liner:

```
open('install.zip', 'wb').write(urllib.urlopen('http://status.calibre-ebook.com/dist/portable/' + result).read())
```

which doesn't have a good memory-efficiency, but still works.

Comment: I don't think they're that bad, if we know what we're doing. Readability and performance are not always the best answers. We can try to improve writability, while not damaging readability so much.

Comment: - not maintainable; - unreadable; - not really testable; - not debugable; - you are likely to be the only one to maintain it; - "we" might not include you in a few months or years (nothing personal, it's just the way it is); - you may need to bump into such one-liners a few times that you didn't code, but you have to maintain to understand my reasoning

Comment: I didn't say maintainability is not important. There are always some areas that "writing faster" is more important than "writing maintainable code". Updater script which is asked, in my opinion, is an instant program that doesn't really require every single point in programming language theory. It's just a toy script with fun, so not using the one-liner in the production code is just enough. That's why I said "they are not always the best answers".

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to download a file from the net, you can use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file ...

Example using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) instead of `urllib2`:

```
import requests, re, urllib

print("Calibre is updating...")
content = requests.get("http://sourceforge.net/projects/calibre/files").content

# determine current version
v = re.search('title="/[0-9.]*/([a-zA-Z\-]*-[0-9\.]*)', content).groups()[0][:-1]
download_url = "http://status.calibre-ebook.com/dist/portable/{0}".format(v)

print("Downloading {0}".format(download_url))
urllib.urlretrieve(download_url, 'install.zip')
# file should be downloaded at this point
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tryed

```
output = open('install.zip', 'wb') // note the "b" flag which means "binary file"
```

Comment: Code without explanation is usual not very useful. Consider adding information what that 'b'-flag actually does for future readers.